# Where's Windows XP standard MIDI SoundFont?

Tags: windows-xp, midi, sound-font

I'm trying to find the standard SoundFont used in WindowsXP's MIDI Wavetable Synthesizer.

I don't know if I get this right, but there seems to be a set of Roland Sound Canvas samples used in XP's wavetable synthesizer. I looked for a SoundFont based on these samples, but either there is none in my Windows installation, or the MIDI playback works in a different
way.

Anyone has an idea where to look for it?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for, it would help if you linked to some of the things you're talking about, so we can help you more effectively

Comment: Definitely Roland samples, but sorry, no idea how to find them. They don't come up when searching for .sf2 files.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem on my own (look below). I tried to stuff my answer up with some links and explanations - maybe others will find it useful. Thank you for your concern :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I figured what is going on.

Basically, Windows XP uses the [DLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLS_format) (Downloadable Soundbank) library. It can be found in `c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\gm.dls` . It should be possible to convert this DLS soundbank to a [SoundFont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundFont) (*.SF2) using a converter - reportedly, [Extreme Sample Converter](http://www.extranslator.com/index.php?page=exsc) offers this functionality.

Anyway, I have found this publicly available SoundFont ([link](http://soundfonts.homemusician.net/collections_soundfonts/roland_sound_canvas_tuned.html)). It sounds almost exactly like Windows's standard MIDI soundbank, so it solves my problem :)

Comment: It looks like the link to the publicly available SoundFont does not link to anything useful anymore

Comment: @dennisschagt File on this page worked for me: https://musical-artifacts.com/artifacts/713

Comment: Archived link to Neo's referenced soundfont `Roland Sound Canvas (Tuned)` filename: `Scc1t2.zip` - http://web.archive.org/web/20140702033834/http://soundfonts.homemusician.net/files/Scc1t2.zip

Comment: I personally like the one Athari referenced (https://musical-artifacts.com/artifacts/713/gm.sf2) which is converted directly from GM.DLS found on Win98/XP/7 (identical file).  I think it sounds better than the 2gmgsmt.sf2 hidden in WinXP's driver.cab

Answer (score 6):

in the archive-file: C:\WINDOWS\Driver Cache\i386\driver.cab

is a *.sf2 - file (called: "2gmgsmt.sf2")

greez

Comment: I unfortunately have no file named driver.cab (windows 7)

Comment: I do with xp, though, and it sounds great (better than the link for the one above). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the filename at least ("2gmgsmt.sf2"), it's easy to look online for some alternative.